# Unable to add firebase authentication to my app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've successfully connected to Firebase, but when I click on "Add Firebase Authentication to your app" and click on accept changes, nothing is happening.

I am not getting any errors as well as I am not getting the message "dependencies added successfully".

I've checked the Gradle section of my app and the dependencies are added correctly, but I am not getting the green star saying "dependencies added successfully".

These are the dependencies that have been added to my project:

```
     dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
          classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
         }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try add this in your Gradle file manually:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
```

Comment: are you sure that you have put this line (apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services') at the end of gradle file ?

Comment: No I just added compile 'com.google.firebase:firrbase-auth:16.0.5' into my build.gradle(Module:app) file

Comment: okay ... so add (apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services') in the end of your gradle file that you have add (compile 'com.google.firebase:firrbase-auth:16.0.5') in it

Comment: Iam getting an error stating " In project 'app' a resolved Google play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version "

Comment: are you sure that you download (google_service.json) from firebase and set it correctly to android project ?

Comment: Yeah I am sure of that ,I've created a new project just now and tried adding firebase authentication to it and it was successful but iam unable to do the same to this project

Comment: i need you to try create another project in firebase and android then connect it step by step again and make sure that (google_service.json) is set up successfully and add all gradle files correctly as i show you in comments then told me what is the error

Comment: Sure I'll do it

Comment: if there is any problem i suggest to you see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EO-_vwfVi7c

Comment: please check this question once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56210382/trouble-with-user-registration-in-firebase