# Trouble with user registration in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've successfully connected to `firebase` and added all required dependencies but i am unable to register users into it.The code I wrote is in this picture I've also provided the `gradle` dependencies list please check where i am going wrong

[The code I've written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvdIj.png)

I've enabled email and password verification in firebase yet it doesnt work.

Here is the list of my dependencies.

```
 dependencies 
 {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
   core:3.0.2'
 }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: What error are u getting?

Comment: Iam getting the message "Cant register with this email id"  which is the else part of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to give more information before the community can help solve your problem for you.

To get more information, I'd suggest logging out the exception and sharing it. Add the following line in the else{} block of your code:

```
Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
```

So it looks something like this (I wasn't able to copy paste your code because it was an image - it's always helpful to share your code as text in questions so others can copy and correct it):

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // your code here
                        } else {
                            //your toast here                               
                Log.w(TAG,"createUserWithEmail:failure",task.getException());
                        }
```

The logged out error can be found in the Logcat section at the bottom of Android Studio:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: No problem. Please can you accept my answer so people know if has been answered.